# How I can insert a text into a textfield with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, e2e-testing, geckodriver

I am working on a project with Python and Selenium.
In the image you can see the code of the input field in which I try to insert my text.

```
<input data-v-382b0a6e="" id="expiration" name="expiration" type="text" required="required" data-test="expiration-input" autocomplete="billing cc-exp" dir="auto" class="form-textbox form-textbox-text form-textbox-entered" style="" aria-invalid="true">
```

[image: Web elements]

My first approach was to use the `.send_keys(variable)` function. The issue there is that the variable month will be inserted in the year. I tried to clear the input field and click into it before, but it didn't help.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-test='expiration-input']"))).send_keys(expMonth)
```

The following image shows the error.

[image: Issue]

I also tried to use a Javascript executor to insert a value into this input field, but it has no value attribute and it won't use this attribute.

I have clue what I can do here anymore.
Has someone a hint for me how I can insert my text into this field?

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#expiration[name='expiration'][data-test='expiration-input']"))).send_keys(expMonth)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='expiration' and @name='expiration'][@data-test='expiration-input']"))).send_keys(expMonth)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help. I tried to use your suggested solution, but I get the same issue as before.

Comment: I don't have enough posts to write in the chat :/

Comment: @kselight You havn't mentioned about any specific issue/error you are facing. You only mentioned **didn't help**. Update the question with text based relavant HTML and error observed.